# Netzke can not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, extjs, netzke

I follow this [tutorial](http://writelesscode.com/blog/2012/10/20/extjs-rails-crud-application-in-7-minutes/) step by step. My ruby version is 1.9.3, and rails version is 3.2.16.

But still can not work. throw me an error:

```
NameError

undefined local variable or method `netzke' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x007ffcb24eb590>

Rails.root: /Users/USER/MyGit/a
```

It seems the root error, so I change the root file

**before:**

```
 netzke
  root to: "welcome#index"
```

**after:**

```
  root to: "welcome#index"
```

But when run again, It throw me another error:

```
NoMethodError in Welcome#index

Showing /Users/tangmonk/MyGit/a/app/views/welcome/index.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `netzke' for #<#<Class:0x007ffcb29cad40>:0x007ffcb29c8248>
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= netzke :tasks, height: 400 %>
Rails.root: /Users/tangmonk/MyGit/a
```

I change the rails version to 4.0, But problem still exist.

So, I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like everything was correct but you forgot to run `bundle install` after you add new gems to Gemfile.